# What is the correct ProGuard definition for latest mp4parser/isoparser library?

Tags: android-proguard

I've been struggling with that here and there -

What is the proguard definitions you need to add to your project proguard configuration file to allow the mp4parser library to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tested with mp4parser version 1.1.7:

```
-keep class * implements com.coremedia.iso.boxes.Box { *; }
-dontwarn com.coremedia.iso.boxes.**
-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.**
-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.ttml.**
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

mp4parser 1.1.22

```
-keep class com.coremedia.iso.** {*;}
-keep class com.googlecode.mp4parser.** {*;}
-keep class com.mp4parser.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.coremedia.**
-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.**
```

Comment: Is this even correct? You have just kept all the classes of the library